# how to pass attributes from a parent to a child element in polymer Using data binding

Tags: data-binding, polymer, polymer-1.0, 2-way-object-databinding

I'm trying to pass an attribute's value from a parent element into it's children,

here is what I'm trying to do :

the parent/child elements that I'm using are defined like this :

```
<parent-element  parent-attr="first"> 

<child-one child-attr="{{parent-attr}}"></child-one>
<child-two child-attr="{{parent-attr}}"></child-two>
...

</parent-element>
```

Inside parent element :

```
<dom-module id="parent-element">
    <template>
            <content parent-attr="{{parent-attr}}"></content>
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer({
            is: "parent-element",
            properties: {
                parentAttr:{
                    type: String,
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

Inside the child element :

```
<dom-module id="child-one">
    <template>
            <content child-attr="{{child-attr}}"></content>
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer({
            is: "child-one",
            properties: {
                childAttr:{
                    type: String,
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: What is the problem with this code ? It should work

Comment: You may have to use the `<child-one child-attr="{{parent-attr}}"></child-one>` and `<child-one child-attr="{{parent-attr}}"></child-one>` instances in parent element's `<template>` section or definition. Then use parent elements instances like this `<parent-element  parent-attr="first"></parent-element>`

Comment: @SG_ well, it doesn't unfortunately

Comment: Have you tried without the dashes inside the handlebars, like this `<child-one child-attr="{{parentAttr}}"></child-one>`. It has to work this way.

Comment: @SG_ did that too,

Comment: the way that you told me on the second comment, it worked, but is it a "have to" or it can be done in another way ? I mean is there a way that I could have both parent and child elements in the index file?